# Simulating non-homogenous Poisson Process with piecewise constant intensity rate

Tags: simulation, poisson-process

Suppose we have a non-homogenous Poisson Process with the following intensity rate:

$$
\lambda(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}5, t \in(1,2],(3,4], \cdots \\ 3, t \in(0,1],(2,3], \cdots\end{array}\right.
$$

and we are asked to simulate this process. Let's consider the process from the time interval $[0,100]$. Now, I am aware that for non-constant intensity rates $\lambda(t)$, a good approach would be to use the thinning method. Here I could consider an upper bound for the intensity to be $\lambda_{\max} = 5$ and proceed with the method.

However, I started thinking that the intensity function is piecewise constant and maybe it would be more efficient to do it otherwise. I have thought that I could:

- Simulate two independent homogenous Poisson Processes, one with $\lambda = 5$ and one with $\lambda = 3$, and then consider the "hits" of the processes on the appropriate time intervals, resulting in only once process. I'm not sure this is a correct approach.
- Simulate a homogenous Poisson Process for every interval $(0,1],(1,2],...$ aided by some loop. This seems inefficient.

If anyone has any suggestions on what the best way to proceed to simulate this process with only two intensity rates, I would appreciate it. I would also like to understand the thought process behind it and, computationally speaking, which method is best.

Comment: By definition, the processes restricted to any disjoint sets of times are *independent.*  Thus you may split your process into two homogeneous processes, simulate them separately, and combine the results.